# Using state and button to remove an element from a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list created like so:

```
return (this.state.limit).fill().map((_,index) => {
  return ( 
   <div key={`${index}`}> Item </div>
  )
)
```

How can I create a button that let's me remove a specific div element as well as reduce the state limit?

Comment: Update the `limit` state (removing the item via setState) and let React render it again.

Comment: Updating the state will only get rid of the last div. I'm looking for a way to remove a div element in the middle of my array.

Comment: Then remove that specific item in the state.

Comment: @FabianSchultz how? The state is currently updated to set the limit of how many is created. How would I specifically remove it in the state?

Comment: Ohh now I see. I'll prepare an example and add an answer.

Comment: Feel free to make it an answer so I can choose it if it's the correct solution I'm looking for! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, you will have to bind almost everything to data. In your example, all those items should be represented by some underlying data. Here's a very basic example showing this:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5'],
    };
  }
  removeItem(item) {
    let data = this.state.data.filter((_, i) => i != item);
    this.setState({ data });
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      {this.state.data.map((item, i) => <div key={i} onClick={() => this.removeItem(i)}>{item}</div>)}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the guideline I needed :)

Comment: @FabianSchultz I deleted that comment so someone else doesn't see that and get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button

```
<button onClick={removeDiv}>
  Remove div
</button>
```

Add function `removeDiv`

```
function removeDiv(){
  this.state.limit.shift()
  this.setState({limit: this.state.limit})
}
```

When changing the state, your component will re-render it self with new state.